# Is freedom of expression more important than religious sensitivities?

Tags: freedom-of-speech, islam, freedom-of-religion

Charlie Hebdo is planning to republish the blasphemous cartoons of Muhammad (P.B.U.H), and when the Fresh president Emmanuel Macron was asked whether he will condemn this action, he categorically stated that he will not condemn cartoons of Prophet Muhammad (P.B.U.H).

My question is: **is it fair to hurt the feelings of 1.5 billion Muslims in the name of freedom of expression by publishing cartoons of their beloved prophet?**

Comment: Questions asking for our opinions on things are off-topic.

Comment: Bold of you to assume that 1.5 billion Muslims are offended. I think rather a vocal minority is offended and the overwhelming majority are either unaware or think to themselves "how tacky/tasteless" and go about their day.

Comment: While I would like to respond to this question if it were something along the lines of "Why has Macron defended the Charlie Hedbo cartoons?" or "Has he done it?", as the question and title are written it seems quite opinion-based, even if we take it as given that Macron said that he would not condemn the cartoons, and that every Muslim in the world had their feelings hurt, as the question states. One person might say yes (as I would), another might say no. As such, it is really unanswerable in a manner that adheres to site guidelines.

Comment: If you change your question to be more objective, it could receive an answer along the lines of (this map) https://www.france24.com/en/20181031-blasphemy-middle-east-asia-bibi-europe-law-religion-ireland (and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.S._v._Austria_(2018))

Comment: Yes, freedom of expression is more important that feelings.

Answer (score 2):

The American view would be that those two rights are harmonious and do not conflict -- religious sensitivities are in far more danger under states without freedom of expression.  Particularly in theocracies, which are the worst possible places for religious sensitivities -- excepting for those with state approved "vanilla" sensitivities.

This Q. also wrongly conflates the views of bigoted Muslim terrorists, (a small minority), with the views of *all* Muslims, who encompass a great variety of less murderous views on this issue.

Comment: I don't get the 2nd paragraph at all, who said anything about terror?

Comment: @dandavis, The Q. mentions Charlie Hebdo which published cartoons of Muhammad, and was subsequently targeted by terrorists.

Comment: There is, of course, more than one American view....

Comment: @Obie2.0, There are many American views, (prior to the revolution some of the States *were* theocracies), but the view in this answer is **the** one in the Constitution.

Comment: Well, this would be the view upheld by current mainstream legal interpretations of the Constitution, but there's no one *American* view, because people in America think different things. Also, I presume there is some space between "violent extremist who wants to kill anyone who blasphemes" and "someone whose feelings were hurt by the cartoons." The question refers to the latter, not the former.

Comment: Is the "American view" really relevant to this question? This is about something happening in France.

Comment: @Philipp, Sure it's relevant.  The problem posed by the Q. seems general enough, and is inspired by an event with international repercussions, a fair number of American cartoonists support Charlie Hebdo.... and the Q. was not tagged "France".

Comment: @Obie2.0, Let's not neglect to distinguish the non-violent "hurt" Muslims from all 1.5b Muslims.  Like Christendom, Islam is a *very* large tent -- both include sects with attitudes toward their respectively varying definitions of "infidels" that run from violent, non-violent but vindictive, non-violent and somewhat annoyable, and varying shades of indifference, and even compassion.   Just as it annoys Episcopalians and Unitarians to be judged as though they were one with the devotees of the Falwells, it's an injustice to the more tolerant Muslims to carelessly associate them with extremists.

Comment: I think the term "American" is used here as a widely recognized standard of free speech, not necessarily what Americans think.  Read in that context, the answer is pretty accurate.